# How to speed up text translation?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, google-translate

Is there an approach to speed up processing?

I have to translate three text fields on each of ~126k samples. This task has an estimated time of over 96 hours:

```py
import pickle
from deep_translator import GoogleTranslator
from tqdm import tqdm

def translate(text):
    return GoogleTranslator(
        source='english',
        target='portuguese').translate(text)

def translate_samples(samples):
    translated_sample = []
    for sample in tqdm(samples):
        translated_sample.append({
            "idx": sample["idx"],
            "qs1": translate(sample["qs1"]),
            "qs2": translate(sample["qs2"]),
            "ans": translate(sample["ans"]),
            "cls":sample["cls"]
            })

    return translated_sample




def perform_tasks():
    with open("resource/dataset/aug.pkl", "rb") as samples_file:
        samples = pickle.load(samples_file)

    translated_sample = translate_samples(samples)

    with open("resource/dataset/aug_pt_br.pkl", "wb") as samples_file:
        pickle.dump(translated_sample, samples_file)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    perform_tasks()

# 0%|                                    | 36/126738 [00:36<96:12:38,  2.14s/it]
```

Could you give me some directions?

Comment: Your task is IO-bound and concurrency methods such as threading or async can help to speed up the process.

Comment: [aiohttp](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/) is a great library to help you get started with async web requests! You won't be able to use the `deep_translator` library directly though, but should be able to rewrite the [core parts](https://github.com/nidhaloff/deep-translator/blob/482855e5665fb89dc30dbcdfe33a15c1da591a4f/deep_translator/google_trans.py#L103) relatively easily. As an aside, do beware that you will probably get blocked by google before you can complete the translation of that many samples, and you should look into purchasing an API key.

Answer (score 0):

You may try other pre-trained models available in hugging face library. Check below sample code might bring down to ~75 hours. for your dataset. You may try batch processing and GPU together to perform more better.

```
from transformers import MarianTokenizer, MarianMTModel
import time

model_name = 'Helsinki-NLP/opus-mt-fr-en'
tokenizer = MarianTokenizer.from_pretrained(model_name)
model = MarianMTModel.from_pretrained(model_name)

# function to get the chunks out of the entire data
def chunks(lst, n):
    for i in range(0, len(lst), n):
        yield lst[i : i + n]

for i, col in enumerate(source_cols):
    start = time.time()
    translations = []
    batch_no = 0
    # encode the source language text
    for source_text in chunks(data[col].tolist(), 500):
        batch_no += 1
        print('batch %d tokenization started' % batch_no)
        batch = tokenizer.encode(source_text, return_tensors='pt', padding=True)
        # predict the output token ids
        print('batch %d prediction started.' % batch_no)
        outputs = model.generate(**batch)
        print('batch %d decoding started.' % batch_no)
        decoded_output = tokenizer.decode(outputs, skip_special_tokens=True)
        translations.extend(decoded_output)
        print('batch %d completed' % batch_no)
    data[target_cols[i]] = translations
    end = time.time()
    print('%.2f hours taken for verbatim %s' % ((end - start)/3600, col))
```